# Is there any NuGet package for adding gettext support in C# / ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, internationalization

I search for a NuGet package that adds support for GNU gettext in C# / ASP.NET MVC applications. The only relevant packages I have been able to find (searching on "[PO](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22PO%22)", "[i18n](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22i18n%22)" or "[gettext](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22gettext%22)") have last-published date back in 2013. This could hint that the packages are not maintained that actively, and with a risk of being obsoleted in the future as consequence.

Are there any mature and still-maintained NuGet packages that adds support for the gettext eco system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually one package that seem to satisfy most of the needs, namely [i18N-Complete](https://www.nuget.org/packages/i18N-Complete/). This includes

- support for plural forms;
- explicit support for Razor markup (allowing l10n of views too);
- it is actually a NuGet package.

My only concern about this package is if it is still actively maintained: its last release was published 1.5 year ago and the last commit in the sources was pushed half a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think this https://github.com/turquoiseowl/i18n is the most robust one. Going to try it myself.

Comment: I have looked at turquoiseowl but it lacks plural form support, which is one of the major strengths of gettext. So that library is unfortunately not an option. :-(

Comment: @  Bart it'ok..now working??

Comment: @JintoJohn I ended up using westwind globalization... not very happy with it. I'm looking forward for the solution that MVC 6 will bring. https://github.com/DamianEdwards/i18nStarterWeb